# Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have problem with frames in Capybara. I switch to one frame and click on Football then on all links on that category but just 2 links are clicked and after that error raises with message that this element is not on current frame.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
Capybara.app_host = 'http://sports.sbobet.com'

module MyCapybaraTest
  class Test
    include Capybara::DSL
    def test
      visit('/')
      page.driver.browser.switch_to.frame 'leftFrame'

      wait_until {page.find('table span.SportName').visible?}
      page.all('table span.SportName').each do |span|
        if (span.text == 'Football')
          span.click
          page.all('div#MarketTbl span.LMenuLeft a').each do |a|
            puts a[:href]
            a.click
            sleep 3
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end

t = MyCapybaraTest::Test.new
t.test
```

Detailed error is:
https://gist.github.com/3252149

I don't know what is wrong since if I remove `sleep 3` then it runs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError` means there is a DOM element on the current page that matches the selector used to find the Selenium element object you're calling a method on, but it's not the same DOM element.

In your case it looks like you're interacting with some navigation links that are common to a set of pages. For example if `page.all('div#MarketTbl span.LMenuLeft a')` returns 3 links, and those 3 links exist on all pages reached by each of those links, if you don't have a `sleep` in the loop, the first two links are probably being clicked on before the page actually changes.

With the `sleep` in the loop, when the second `a.click` is called, the `a` object was found on the first page, but the link it represents is now a different, physical DOM node because the second page has had time to load.

I would try taking the loops out and find and click on each link individually.

Also be aware that `#all` does not use Capybara's `wait_until` functionality, so it can behave unintuitively with slow applications.